# How to define a table in mysql to save 4 not mandtory dropdown values

Tags: mysql

Hi i have 4 drop downs in my application like

**dropdown1_ofType_A,dropdown2_ofType_B,dropdown3_ofType_C,dropdown4_ofType_D**

I have to define team association table bit of confusion in defining a table here is my idea

Tabel Columns

```
DropdownID,DropdownValue,DropdwonType
```

or

```
AType_DropdownID,AType_DropdownValue,BType_DropdownID,BType_DropdownValue,CType_DropdownID,CType_DropdownValue,DType_DropdownID,DType_DropdownValue
```

**summary of the question is**

To store not mandatory drop down values create table with three columns with 4 rows better or 8 columns with 1 row is better.

Answer (score 0):

As per Normalization form of database it's good to go with 3 columns with 4 rows is better. Because if in future there is 1 more value then you can add a new row for the same but in second option you have to add new column which is not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown value not mandatory to store so you have to create table with 3 columns instead of 8.There is no meaning to create dropdown wise columns.